# Delegated event triggering even when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have the following code:

```
 // Define controls
$('.play-video').click(function(){
    // Get the video element
    var video = $(this).parent().parent().find('video');
    // Play the video
    $(video).get(0).play()

    // Remove the play class and add the pause class so the same button will pause the video
    $(this).removeClass('play-video');
    $(this).addClass('pause-video');

    // Set pause text
    $(this).text('Pause');
});



$(document).on('click','.pause-video',function(){
    console.log('pausing...');
    // Get the video element
    var video = $(this).parent().parent().find('video');
    // Play the video
    $(video).get(0).pause()

    // Remove the play class and add the pause class so the same button will pause the video
    $(this).removeClass('pause-video');
    $(this).addClass('play-video');

    // Set pause text
    $(this).text('Play');
});
```

Problem is, that the second click event should trigger on

```
.pause-video
```

only but also triggers on

```
.play-video
```

Question is: What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance,
G3

Comment: Please provide the HTML also. Better, provide a working demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've attached the "play" event handler directly to the button instead of using delegation. That handler will continue to fire because of that, even if you change the class.

Delegation works through event bubbling, and the selector you pass in to the `.on()` call is re-examined with every event. That is not the case with handlers that are directly attached: once those are active, they're active until they're removed or until the DOM element itself is removed. Changing the particulars of the DOM element won't make a difference.

Your problem can therefore be solved by using delegation for both cases.

Comment: Well I've attached the first click event to .play-video, shouldn't that fix that?

Comment: @g3mini **no** - you're attaching it *directly*, and that selector (`.play-video`) is only evaluated at the point you attach the handler. Later changes have no effect. Changes *would* have an effect if you used the same technique as for `.pause-video` - `.on()` instead of `.click()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is close. but your first event handler also needs to be delegated too:

```
$(document).on('click', '.play-video', click(function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

try to stop immediage propagation $('.play-video').click

Comment: This will not help - the "play" handler will be invoked before the "pause" handler anyway.

Comment: actually it have to work, but 2nd handler not getting executed ever.

So its better to use "on" for both it will work as expected

Comment: yes I mean when you use "e.stopImmediatePropagation()" in first handler then 2nd handler is not executing.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that jQuery can't track object changes on the fly. Just use one click event, and determine what to do inside this:

```
$('.play-stop-video').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('play')) {
        // Current play button code here....
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('stop')) {
        // Current stop button code here....
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('play').toggleClass('stop');
});
```

$(something).click( ... will runs when the page loads, and attach the click events to the play and stop buttons. However, you don't have any stop buttons at this time, so the click event for this will be discarded...

Comment: With delegation, jQuery **can** track object changes on the fly. The selector passed to `.on()` is re-evaluated with each event that bubbles up to the document level.